# Making two different column layouts on the same page

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I need to have to separate column layouts on the same page. one with 3 columns and another 4.

The 3 column layout is working but I cannot get the 4 columns one to work. Making a separate class for the 4 column layout is not working

css for 3 columns

```
  float: left;
  width: 32.55%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}



/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;

}
```

I have expected making a different class for the 4 column layout to work. eg class="4columns" . Which does not seem to work

Comment: Do you remove the `3columns` class when you adding `4columns` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox gives you a simple way to achieve any division of space you want.

Just by applying `display: flex;` to your containers, the immediate child elements, columns in this case, become flexible items. There are a lot of useful configuration options but if you just want to control the width of the columns, `flex-basis` works great.

A good resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
* {
  box-sizing-border-box;
}

.my-columns {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.column {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.my-columns-3 .column {
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
}

.my-columns-4 .column {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-columns my-columns-3">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="my-columns my-columns-4">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
  <div class="column">Column 4</div>
</div>
```